# How to run batch process 5 files at a time, then continue on with the next 5 files that are within a list?

Tags: python, batch-processing

I have some code where i have a list with some .bat file in them where i later execute each of those bat files all at once.  However what i would like to do is execute only 5 at a time, and then once the processing is complete it moves on to the next 5 in that list.

```
for ProcProfileCFG in ProcProfileCFGs
     IETrajBatFile = ProcProfileCFG[3]
     ProcProfileFile = ProcProfileCFG[2]

#This command then runs all of the bat files with in ProcProfileCFGs at once
#where x[3] is the bat file name i.e. "IE_trajectory.bat"
res = Pool().amap(os.system, ['powershell.exe ./' + x[3] for x in ProcProfileCFGs])
```

So i just want it to run this command for the first 5 files, so they all run simultaneously then once those files have been completed run the next 5 simultaneously, and so on and so on until its gone through all of them.  Instead of all at once, which is what it is currently doing.

Comment: What about just wrapping your `Pool` in a for loop that iterates over every 5 files and pools those together? This will allow 5 files to complete and then it will move on to the next 5 files, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specifiy the number of workers when creating the Pool.

```
with Pool(5) as p:
        p.map(func, list)
        p.close()
        p.join()
```

Note that it will not work on the same 5 files simultanously and move to the next 5 ones in order. But it creates a queue with 5 workers and when a worker is done, another one begins. It ensures that you'll only have 5 files beeing treated at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Slice the batch file population to chunks

import multiprocessing

```
def handle_batch_file(file_name):
    # dummy code
    # print(file_name)
    return file_name


BATCH_SIZE = 5

BATCH_FILES = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']


def main():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(BATCH_SIZE)
    counter = 0
    while True:
        sub_list = BATCH_FILES[counter * BATCH_SIZE: (counter + 1) * BATCH_SIZE]
        print('Calling "map" with sub list {}'.format(sub_list))
        dummy_results = p.map(handle_batch_file, sub_list)
        if len(BATCH_FILES) <= (counter + 1) * BATCH_SIZE:
            break
        counter += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output

```
Calling "map" with sub list ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
Calling "map" with sub list ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
Calling "map" with sub list ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `multiprocessing`. An example, for reading `CSVs`, named as `file1.csv`, `file2.csv`, etc:

```
import multiprocessing

output=[]
data = range(0,len(files))

def f(x):
    pd.read_csv(file_name+x+'.csv')

def mp_handler():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(64)
    r=p.map(f, data)
    return r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    output.append(mp_handler())
```

Comment: This is not what was asked. The constraint is that the processes need to be run 5 at a time, not all at once like you code will do.